# Glass in Shower has Strange Glare

Tags: materials, light, lighting, glass

**Issue:** I can't seem to fix this strange shower glare that's happening at the top of my glass for a shower. Can anyone help me figure out how to remove this glare, and/or explain why it's happening?

**Context:** I know the source of it is caused by an Area Light above it, which is used to light the shower area, but I can't figure out how to remove the strange glare from the light that reflects into the glass. It also reflects on the ceiling behind it, and I don't know how to get rid of this. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

[Link to downloadable file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzkddiag5243kjr/Bathroom%20BG%20D26.blend?dl=0)

The glare:
[image]

The Area Light setup above the shower:
[image]

The shower glass node setup (includes a raindrop material for creating condensation on the glass):
[image]

Comment: Those look like fireflies. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40040/fireflies-noise-on-glossy-material

Comment: Thanks! I believe the issue is now resolved -- they appear to be related to the "raindrop" normal image that I had worked into the glass BSDF. I just decided not to include the normal and now those strange reflections are gone. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯