# Impossible to eliminate fireflies Cycles 2.79

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I've been struggling with cycles, I always have fireflies in 4k and even going as far as 5000 samples, I'm using an HDRI and the denoiser won't help. I have been searching the whole web by now, I'm looking for answers so I would appreciate some help.

Multiple importance is ON but dont help.
Clamp options dont do the work properly.

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce fireflies in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Comment: see if any of the solutions outlined here works for you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40142 and https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies