# any help with this noisy render?

Tags: rendering

im not sure if this is the right place to post this, if not i apologize

i made this render and as you can see, its very noisy where the chairs cast shadows, any suggestions? im rendering at 300 samples and i have tried increasing the samples, using the filter glossy, larger lights, decreasing the number of bounces and im also using pro lighting skyes, thanks

[image: noisy render]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Comment: @someonewithpc Telling someone to go to Google is probably not the best way to welcome a new user to the site.

Comment: In complement to the link indicated above. You can also play with the "clamp direct" and "clamp indirect" values (try what is better for you, even if this may lost accuracy). And yes : welcome in BSE (dont worry i am still learning : )

Comment: Use "multiple importance sampling in lights and environment": http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5309/when-should-mis-be-used-and-when-should-it-be-disabled/5397#5397 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8152/what-is-multiple-importance-sample-option/8156#8156. Additionally try using branched path tracing: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/what-is-branched-path-tracing-and-how-is-it-useful Those shite specs are called fireflies. Try some of the suggestins on this post : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles